# How can I set the title_for_layout in the default PagesController?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I cannot set `title_for_layout` in the PagesController that comes by default with CakePHP 1.3.

I am using the following code in the display function:

```
$this->set('title_for_layout','some title');
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Update: The **`$title_for_layout`** is deprecated as of 2.5 [Link](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#layouts)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your controller, the corresponding value is `$this->pageTitle`.

**UPDATE**

Oops, as noted in the comments, this is the 1.2 solution. 1.3 possibilities (after doing some research) include:

1. Ensuring that `$title_for_layout` is being echoed in the layout
2. Placing the `$this->set()` code in the view rather than in the controller

Comment: As an addition: you can also set this value in the corresponding View which would be even more MVC

Comment: Sorry guys but $this->PageTitle is for cakephp 1.2 and not for 1.3 in my knowledge. In any case when used in cakephp 1.2 produces an error.

Comment: Apologies. I missed the 1.3 specification in your question if that wasn't part of an edit. It does look like that's gone away in 1.3 (http://book.cakephp.org/view/1561/Migrating-from-CakePHP-1-2-to-1-3). I haven't used 1.3 yet, but a read of the docs indicates that what you're doing should work if the rest of the context is correct.

Comment: At the risk of stating the obvious, are you echoing the `$title_for_layout` variable in your actual layout? e.g.  `<title><?php echo $title_for_layout; ?></title>`?

Comment: Looks like the solution was to put the $this->set() code in the view and not in the controller.

Answer (score 3):

If you'd like to mimic the behavior of cake 1.2, you can do the following:

In your app_controller, create the following method:

in app/app_controller.php (you may need to create this file if you haven't already)

```
public $pageTitle;

public function beforeRender() {
    $this->set('title_for_layout', $this->pageTitle);
}
```

Then in any of your action methods, you may then use the pageTitle as you would in 1.2.

```
public function index() {
    $this->pageTitle = 'Some Title';
}
```

The beforeRender() method will be called after your controllers have finished processing, but prior to the layout being rendered, thus allowing you to set variables for the layout.

Answer (score 2):

In the action method, try this:

```
function index()
{
    $this->pageTitle= 'Your Title';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just thought I'd add to any new people finding this solution, you can do `$this->set('title', $title);` in CakePHP 1.3 inside the controller and the title will be rendered automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
$this->assign('title', 'Some title');
```

and in ctp :

```
<title><?= $this->fetch('title'); ?></title>
```

It work in CakePHP 3.0

Answer (score 1):

For CakePHP 3.x,

you can follow the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26603729/80353)

Essentially,

Inside `UsersController.php`:

```
$this->set('title', 'Login');
```

Inside `src/Template/Layouts/default.ctp`

above the `$this->fetch('title');`

write:

```
if (isset($title)) {
    $this->assign('title', $title); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `beforeRender()` instead. Put the following in AppController:

```
class AppController extends Controller {
    var $content;

    function beforeRender() {
        $this->set('content',$this->content);
    }            
}
```

And in the controller, you can just do:

```
function index() {
    $this->content['title'] = '123'; }
```

That'll do the trick.