# How to alter view blocks content from controller in CakePHP 3?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Inside Layouts/default.ctp you will see something like this  at line 39:

```
        <div class="header-title">
            <span><?= $this->fetch('title') ?></span>
        </div>
```

`fetch` suggests that it is a view block. I couldn't find this view block anywhere.

Currently it just displays the capitalized plural form of controller. Meaning to say if you are at `/users/add` , the `fetch('title');` gives you `'Users'`

I want to change it. So I tried the following:

```
$this->set('title', 'Login');
```

in the `/users/login` controller action.

Did not work.

I also tried

```
$this->assign('title', 'Login');
```

in the `/users/login` controller action.

I get this error message:

```
Call to undefined method App\Controller\UsersController::assign()
```

I read the docs and from [here](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views.html#view-blocks)

I get

> Assigning a block’s content is often useful when you want to convert a
>   view variable into a block. For example, you may want to use a block
>   for the page title, and sometimes assign the title as a view variable
>   in the **controller**:

Emphasis mine.

This suggests that you can use `assign` inside controller. I think I have proven that this is false.

Perhaps there is a typo in the documents. Please advise how I can set the title

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change page title in CakePHP 2.5?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26345051/how-to-change-page-title-in-cakephp-2-5)

Comment: i indicated that this is for CakePHP 3.x. So I disagree with the duplicate flag.

Comment: but both uses same functionality , stackoverflow is not a place to have a question of how to sort an array by value question for each php version !!

Comment: I agree. Then in that case, you should also mark that 2.5 question as a duplicate of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628963/how-can-i-set-the-title-for-layout-in-the-default-pagescontroller

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how to do it thanks to dakota of the irc channel #cakephp.

Inside `UsersController.php`:

```
$this->set('title', 'Login');
```

Inside `src/Template/Layouts/default.ctp`

above the `$this->fetch('title');`

write:

```
if (isset($title)) {
    $this->assign('title', $title); 
}
```

The question would be how does cakephp 3 set the default value?

Answer is found in https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.0/src/View/View.php#L468

Append image just in case link rot

[image]

Where you can see that it will be defaulted to the view path

Comment: What do you mean?
I need to assign a default parameter "page_header_image" (rendered in my template) and, in some cases, override the page_header_image for specific pages.
I am able to write $this->assign('page_header_image', '...'); in the specific view, but what about default page_header_image value?

Answer (score 1):

> Assigning a block’s content is often useful when you want to **convert a view variable** into a block. For example, you may want to use a block for the page title, and sometimes assign the title as a **view variable** in the controller:

The above does not suggests that you should use assign in your controller (notice the bold). The above suggest that instead of using

```
$this->start('title');
echo $title;
$this->end()
```

You can use

```
$this->assign('title', $title);
```

and the `$title` variable should be set from your controller.

If you want to do it the proper way from your controller you have to write

```
$this->set('title', $title);
```

and from your layout/view file write

```
echo $title;
```

Comment: The documentation uses a cumbersome way to express this idea. It is not immediately obvious to a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

Cake 3 (and 2?) give you the possibility to override the 'View' class. This is a good place to call assign().

Example:

```
namespace App\View;

use Cake\View\View;

class AppView extends View
{
    public function initialize()
    {
        $this->assign('the_block_name', "Hello from AppView");
    }
}
```

In Layout/default.ctp:

```
<?= $this->fetch('the_block_name') ?>
```

If you, as in my case, want to have a 'default' block defined, the above solution works great. You can override the default block in any view file (.ctp) like this:

```
$this->start('the_block_name');
    echo '<h4>Hello from current view!</h4>';
$this->end();
```